# how to make a total data insert a table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to automatically calculate total for sales, expenses & bank-in

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("select * from new");

$x = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["D_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["D_id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["D_item"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["D_sales"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["D_expenses"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["D_bankin"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
$x++;
}
?>

<?php

$result1 = mysql_query("select * from new");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
        <td><?php echo $row1["D_totalsales"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row1["D_totalexpenses"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1["D_totalbankin"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of fire two query for that. You can do the same in a single query.

Change your query to

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT *,SUM(`D_sales`) as D_totalsales ,SUM(`D_expenses`) as D_totalexpenses ,SUM(`D_totalbankin`) as D_totalbankin FROM new");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_date"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_id"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_item"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_sales"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_expenses"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_bankin"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_totalsales"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_totalexpenses"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["D_totalbankin"]; ?></td>
</tr> 
?>
```

Comment: thank you. but it doesnt calculate well. how? any idea? btw, thanks again :)

Comment: What you mean by doesn't calculate well ? Show your output ? What's goes wrong ?

Comment: it just show a normal table.
for column table, empty. no calculation. t.t
btw, how to show? sorry im new here & im students

Comment: You will get values in `$row["D_totalsales"];` , etc.. Check my updated answer for more explanation

Comment: <?php
 $result1 = mysql_query("select *,SUM(D_sales) as D_totalsales ,SUM(D_expenses) 
    as D_totalexpenses ,SUM(D_bankin) as D_totalbankin FROM new");
 ?>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">Total</td>
   <td><?php echo $row["D_totalsales"] ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $row["D_totalexpenses"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["D_totalbankin"]; ?></td>
  </tr>

Comment: @NurAmirahMohdNasser - You are not fetching the result. Check my updated answer it will solve you problem.

Comment: so it will be like this ?

<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Date</td>
  <td>Purchase ID</td>
  <td>Item</td>
  <td>Sales [RM]</td>
  <td>Expenses [RM]</td>
  <td>Bank In [RM]</td>
  
 </tr>

Comment: <?php
$x = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,SUM(D_sales) as D_totalsales ,SUM(D_expenses) as D_totalexpenses ,SUM(D_totalbankin) as D_totalbankin FROM new");

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["D_date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_id"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_item"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_sales"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_expenses"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_bankin"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_totalsales"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_totalexpenses"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["D_totalbankin"]; ?></td>
</tr> 
  
<?php
$x++;
}
?>

Comment: @NurAmirahMohdNasser - yeah it should be like this. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT SUM(D_sales), ... FROM table_name
```

Answer (score -1):

You can using mysql_num_rows()

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: @NurAmirahMohdNasser 
`$result = mysql_query("select * from new");
echo mysql_num_rows($result); // Will output amount of strings returned by mysql_query()`

Comment: @NurAmirahMohdNasser this is not applied to any fields it gives us total number of record returned by query.